# Unknown Blank activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to open a pdf file stored in my assets folder. The code i am using is given below. The code is working nicely but the issue i am facing is when i press the back button after the pdf is open i get to the blank screen, i have to go back one more time to reach the screen from where pdf launch was initialized. can anyone help me with this. Thanks

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        CopyReadAssets();    
    }

    private void CopyReadAssets() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "git.pdf");
        try {
            in = assetManager.open("git.pdf");
            out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/git.pdf"),
                "application/pdf");

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you invoking this activity from another activity?  What is in `R.layout.main` (i.e. your `main.xml` layout)?

Comment: @AleksG yes i am invoking this from another activity. i have tried this with removing the setcontentview line also still getting the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the issue is that you are invoking this activity from another one - and then from this one you're invoking yet another one to actually show the PDF file.  When the user presses 'back' from the PDF, you end up seeing this activity; then you press 'back' again - and end up on the original calling one.

Instead, don't create the second activity.  Move `CopyReadAsset` and `copyFile` methods into your first activity and on button click (or whatever the trigger is) call your `CopyReadAsset` method.

There is no need for this activity to ever exist.